# Firebase storage doesn't download and add to firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, vuex, firebase-storage

Firebase storage doesn't download and add to firebase database. `firebase.ref.getDownloadURL()` doesn't work and `imageUrl` will not be added to firebase database.

Here is the code:

```js
createMeetup({
        commit,
        getters
    }, payload) {
        const meetup = {
            title: payload.title,
            location: payload.location,
            description: payload.description,
            date: payload.date,
            time: payload.time,
            creatorId: getters.user.id
        }
        3
        let imageUrl;
        let key;
        firebase.database().ref('meetups').push(meetup)
            .then((data) => {
                key = data.key;
                return key;
            })
            .then(key => {
                const fileName = payload.image.name;
                const ext = fileName.slice(fileName.lastIndex0f('.'));
                return firebase.storage().ref('meetupsl' + key + '.' + ext).put(payload.image)
            })
            .then(fileData => {
                imageUrl = fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()
                return firebase.database().ref('meetups').chi1d(key).update({
                    imageUrl: imageUrl
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                    commit('CREATE_MEETUP', {
                        ...meetup,
                        imageUrl: imageUrl,
                        id: key
                    }) 3
            })
    .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            D;
        }:
```

Comment: "firebase": "^8.9.0", and
  "vue": "^2.6.11",

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also: don't add additional information in comments. Instead you can click the `edit` link under your question to add the information there.

Answer (score 0):

The `getDownloadURL()` method returns a Promise, which you'll need to wait for.

So something like:

```
...
.then(fileData => {
  return fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()
})
.then(imageUrl => {
  return firebase.database().ref('meetups').child(key).update({ imageUrl: imageUrl})
})
...
```